# VB6 & Source Safe

Tags: vb6, visual-sourcesafe

We have multiple developers working on the same code base. We also are trying to use SourceSafe (6.0)

When one developer makes code changes to their local copy, we note it in a list of changed objects for this release.

When it's time to compile our next release, we open the "master" copy, update all the changes from SourceSafe to the master copy, then compile.

At this point, all the other developers code is now out of sync with the master copy, and we need to get all the changes pushed downhill to all the developers local copies, so we're all looking at the same version of source at the start of a new release cycle.

Is there a way to have SourceSafe update the local copies with the latest changes, or do we need to do it manually basaed on the list of changed objects (which is what we're doing now...) Please don't tell me to use "Get Latest Version".  It only works on one file at a time, and is the process we're using now anyway.

Comment: Wow, do two wrongs make a right? I think you need to "get latest version" for your language *and* your source control.

Comment: With a client base of 1000+ users and MS's recent announcement of support for VB6 runtime pretty much ties my hands for moving from VB6.  However SourceSafe can be replaced..

Answer (score 6):

I believe your process is simply incorrect. When your devs get in, just have everyone Get Latest.  When your developers want to make a change, have them check out the file.  This way, it's one dev working on a single file at a time.

If you want multiple people working on the same file, I'd switch to subversion (there is a [vb plugin](http://svnvb6.tigris.org/) for it).

There is a reason why the SCC tools work the way they do - it's been tried and tested over the last 20 years.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll pass it around.. Makes sense too. Always check in when complete, always get latest version when starting a new assignment..

Comment: +1 @MikeD: you might also have a rule like this: before checking in you must get latest version of any files you haven't changed, and check compatibility with your changes. You might like to think about standard automatic tests and maybe a daily build too. One step at a time though! (We don't have a daily build yet but we're working on it.) Beware of multiple people working on the same file in subversion in Vb6 - see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680/using-subversion-with-vb6

Comment: I agree Subversion is far less heachache when working on multiple files. Although I recommend using TortoiseSVN instead of a VB6 IDE plugin.