# Which open source Source Controls products integrate with Microsoft VB6?

Tags: version-control, vb6

I'm looking to possibly move away from CVS (to maybe SVN).

Anyone know which open source version control systems integrate with the VB6 IDE (automatic checkouts, etc.) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVN will work with VB6. there is a VB6 version of SVN that intergrates with the IDE called SVNVB6.

Let me direct you to: [svnvb6.tigris.org](http://svnvb6.tigris.org/)

Comment: Except that it does not allow you to work with Subversion as you would with, say C#.  The reason for this is that .frx files are binary, thus Subversion can't merge changes. Thus you must set .frx files to be checked out exclusively.  Kind of a pain.

Comment: See also the question *Using subversion with VB6* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680/using-subversion-with-vb6

Answer (score 3):

[Tortoise SVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) attaches to Windows and you can use it with anything including VB6, .NET or just files on your PC.

Comment: See also the question *Using subversion with VB6* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680/using-subversion-with-vb6

Answer (score 0):

Visual SVN integrates with Visual Studio, although I don't know about the VB6 IDE:

http://www.visualsvn.com/

There are some answers here regarding Subversion and VB6:

[Using Subversion with Visual Basic 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680/using-subversion-with-vb6)