# TortoiseSVN - "Save Form As" command in VB6 doesn't open any menu

Tags: windows, svn, vb6, tortoisesvn

I started working on a legacy software that uses Visual Basic 6 with TortoiseSVN on Windows.

When I work from the trunk, I am able to use the "Save Form As" contextual menu command to duplicate a form.
When doing the same when working on a branch, the command does not have any effect.

- I have tried moving the project directory to the SVN ignore list.
- I have also tried to take it out of source control all together.
- I created a new repository and checked out the code. From this new repository, I could not copy a form in either the trunk or the branch.

I still cannot copy an existing form.
This tells me there might be an issue with file access permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes `.frm` files have an accompanying `.frx` file (a binary file). Check whether this file is read-write. You may need to lock it in SVN. Since it is a binary file, the [recommended practise](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24762/15639) is to mark it as `needs-lock` in SVN. VB6 sometimes fails to show helpful error messages if the `.frm` is read-write but the `.frx` is read-only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The associated .frx file is R/W already. I marked it as "needs-lock" in SVN as you suggested but this didn't change the behavior.