# How can I work on a Visual Basic 6.0 project on two different PCs?

Tags: version-control, vb6

Currently me and my partner are working on a project in Visual Basic 6.0, but we have no idea how can we work together as we live far from each other. Is there a source where we both can work on same project with different PCs?

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

Source control tools are designed to fix this problem, by allowing you to share code repositories to a private server or a cloud provider like GitHub which you can then deny or allow access to other individuals or contributors.

Out of all the tools I suggest [`Git`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) because it is flexible and can be used with most IDE'S or on the command line with a minimal learning curve. It is  aslo flexible in the fact that you can deploy it to a provider like GitHub or Gitbucket for more community-based projects or Azure devops which is enterprise ready with a free subscription tear and if you feel more comfortable with a private server that is possible too.

[This tutorial](https://product.hubspot.com/blog/git-and-github-tutorial-for-beginners) is a good tutorial for beginners who want to use Git with a provider like GitHub

Answer (score 2):

Subversion or Git are great tools for collaborating on source code for any programming language with someone else, whether the person is on the other side of the world or even in the same room. There's lots of basic tutorials out there if you haven't used them before.

Specifically for VB6: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24680/using-subversion-with-visual-basic-6) has great advice on how to setup Subversion with VB6. And [this one is about Git and VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462480/using-git-with-vb6).

Answer (score 1):

Any kind of cloud-based storage allows for cross-system editing/working on projects. Depending on your needs and if you need to be able to work simultaneously, or separately...

Working simultaneously won't work with the following suggestion, since you won't know what the other has done to the project. For that the other suggestions will be better suited like GitHub

### How I work on the same project over different systems using cloud storage:

I have three PC's that I want to be able to work on projects in Visual Basic 6.0. I've simply created a [Google Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Drive) and run the projects from there. On all systems the drive is configured to always sync on changes.

As I save the project, the new files are synced and updated. When I switch computers, the updated files are there.

You will need to have the IDE installed per system.